Does VSCode support other custom variable memory editor extention for debug other than hex-editor extention ？
I'm going to develop a custom debug extension, and the memory editor function is going to be custom developed.
But I find VSCode variable memory read button(View Binary Data)is only bound to hex-editor extension.
(VSCode source code:src/vs/workbench/contrib/debug/browser/variablesView.ts)
So is there any some way to register my custom memory editor to VSCode variable memory read button or I can only use hex-editor for memory read?

Expect:Bind custom debug variable memory editor to VSCode variable memory read button(View Binary Data) other than use hex-editor.
